# CSRF token missing or incorrect explanation

Tags: django, csrf

i am just a beginner and starting with some tutorials on web, i can not understand why this isn't working for me:

my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf


class MainPage(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render_to_response("helloworld.html")


class TestHandler(View):
    def post(self, request):
        q = {}
        q.update(csrf(request))
        #return render_to_response('test.html', q)
        return render_to_response('test.html', {'q':q}, context_instance=RequestContext(self.request))

    def get(self, request):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
    return HttpResponse(q)
```

and my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
from views import MainPage, TestHandler

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
     url(r'^hello$', MainPage.as_view(), name='home'),
     url(r'^testform/', TestHandler.as_view()),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

helloworld.html

```
>->-<html>
>->->-<head>
>->->->-<title>Hello, World!</title>
>->->-</head>
>->->-<body>
>->->->-<form method="post"  action="/testform/" >                                                                                                           
    {% csrf_token %}
>->->-<input name="q">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
>->->-</body>
>->-</html>
```

test.html

```
>-<body>
>-Hello {{q}}
>-</body>
```

This is running on django 1.6, I read most of post and still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you have pasted is a bit of a mess, you are using Class Based Views but yet you have mixed them with function based views (also half of the declarations are missing).

Enable the CSRF Middlware in your settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Fix your views to proper Class Based Views, what you have pasted is totally wrong:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView, TemplateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy


# Create the form in your forms.py
from .forms import (
    MyTestForm,
)

class MainPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = "test.html"

class TestHandler(CreateView):
    form_class = MyTestForm
    template_name = "helloworld.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Create your form template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post"  action="/testform/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input name="q">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```